# Column count of mysql.user is wrong. Expected 42, found 44. The table is probably corrupted

Tags: mysql

Currently I'm using the newest version of ISPConfig 3. Today I wanted to add a db and user. It didn't work. Then I tried it on PHPmyadmin and it didn't work.

When I tried to add a user in PHPMyadmin Users Panel I received the following error message:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '* TO 'test'@'localhost'' at line 1

The output from /var/log/mysql/error.log:

> [ERROR] Column count of mysql.user is wrong. Expected 42, found 44.
>   The table is probably corrupted

Mysql Version: 5.5.55-0+deb8u1
PHPMyadmin Version: 4:4.2.12-2+deb8u2

Debian Linux 8

Comment: Please edit your question and include the SQL-query you tried.

Comment: i went to the phpmyadmin users tab and wanted to add the user there.

Comment: The 2nd error indicates that the version of the user table is out of sync of the version of your MySQL server. That's something you need to confirm ASAP. Although, MySQL should not have even started under such circumstances.

Comment: how to fix that?

Comment: It starts up normally: /etc/init.d/mysql restart
[ ok ] Restarting mysql (via systemctl): mysql.service.

Comment: Try run **mysql_upgrade** .

Comment: @jirarium it worked, I think it could be as accepted answer

Answer (score 129):

I had the same problem when I updated the mysql server from 5.5 to 5.7 in Debian 8 (jessie). In rare cases, it probably happens if you update directly bypassing the sequences of versions. (Many people do this, but such upgrades are not officially supported). 
In my case, it worked fine when I executed the command below:

```
mysql_upgrade --force -uroot -p
```

I hope this will help you

Comment: after Linux automatically updated mysql from 5.7 to 8.0 I ran into strange problems, this is one of them. Thank you, this command fixed them

Comment: you might need sudo

Comment: that solved for me too. But I use MAMP PRO, so for me the command is: `/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql_upgrade -u --force root --password=[mypassword] -h 127.0.0.1` >> for readers: swap '[mypassword]' with yours.

Comment: Checklist: (1) make sure the mysql_upgrade `--version` matches your server, (2) `--port NNNN` for an alternate port.

Comment: worked for me as well. The log file was not written because I did not run as sudo but I think that's ok.

Answer (score 30):

Migrating from mariadb 10 to mysql 5.6 saw similar issues. The error message I received, was slightly different than the others listed on this page... which, of course, means it required a different solution. Upon attempting to modify a user record I received the following error:

> Column count of mysql.user is wrong. Expected 43, found 46. The table is probably corrupted

Some of the advice above helped frame the problem. After taking a look at a similar server (to the mysql 5.6 one), I compared the fields in the both the "corrupted" user table (from the mariadb 10 mysql.users table) & the "functional" user table in the other mysql 5.6 mysql.users table.

I removed the three problematic fields using the mysql cli & the following commands:

```
mysql -u root -p
use mysql;
alter table mysql.user drop column default_role;
alter table mysql.user drop column max_statement_time;
alter table mysql.user drop column password_expired;
quit
```

Problem resolved!

Comment: When I run `use mysql;` It gives me error `ERROR 1820 (HY000): You must reset your password using ALTER USER statement before executing this statement.`

Comment: Thanks worked like a charm ! Missed almost an 1hr trying to fix this!

Comment: Be careful doing this. Make sure you only do it if you know you have 3 extra columns. It's still risky.

Answer (score 24):

This worked for me:

```
mysql_upgrade -uroot -p
```

and add your password root

Comment: It should be run with `sudo`. Otherwise, an error occurs: `Could not create the upgrade info file '/var/lib/mysql/mysql_upgrade_info' in the MySQL Servers datadir, errno: 13`

Comment: `The mysql_upgrade client is now deprecated. The actions executed by the upgrade client are now done by the server.
To upgrade, please start the new MySQL binary with the older data directory. Repairing user tables is done automatically. Restart is not required after upgrade.`

Answer (score 6):

In my case, and following the recommendation of the error message, I ran:

```
root@mysql-190877524-gm3j4:/# mysql_upgrade -uroot -p***
Checking if update is needed.
Checking server version.
Running queries to upgrade MySQL server.
Checking system database.
mysql.columns_priv                                 OK
mysql.db                                           OK
mysql.engine_cost                                  OK
mysql.event                                        OK
mysql.func                                         OK
mysql.general_log                                  OK
mysql.user                                         OK
Upgrading the sys schema.
Checking databases.
[...]
Upgrade process completed successfully.
Checking if update is needed.
```

That solved everything.

Answer (score 4):

Had the same trouble today on debian (jessie) and another ami linux box. 
Removing the password expired column from mysql user table fixed the issue for me.

```
mysql> alter table mysql.user drop column password_expired;
```

Comment: mine was is_role

Answer (score 3):

I moved from `mariadb` to `mysql` because i was unable to change the `myriadb` `data directory` on `centos 7 x 64`.

on `mysql` When i tried adding new user other than root. i got

```
column count of mysql.user is wrong expected 45 found 48
```

i tried

```
mysql_upgrade  -uroot -p
```

and

```
mysql_upgrade --force -uroot -p
```

but still got the same error.
so i went ahead and added `new user manually` in `mysql.user` table by copying all details from other rows having `root` username.

```
restart service mysqld
```

and done.

Answer (score 2):

Today I ran into the same problem after I did a dist-upgrade of a Debian Jessie 8 staging box. After some Investigation I found out, that the mysql table structure differs from what mysql-5.5.55 expects to find. I just compared the corrupted mysql database with a freshly installed one and created a little patch file, that should correct the error. Not sure if this works under other conditions, too. So, be careful using this patch and backup /var/lib/mysql and /etc/mysql before doing something nasty ;) I'll take no responsibility for any kind of damages possibly arising by this patch. Use it at your very own risk.

First of all MAKE BACKUPS!! and even more BACKUPS!! e.g. you could give mysqlsafebackup a try (Look at https://github.com/VerboteneZone/MySQLSafeBackup), an encrypting and compressing MySQL backup solution, written by me.

Download the following patch to your box:

```
# wget https://download.rent-an.expert/mysql-patch-5.5.55.sql.gz
```

Make sure, that no instance is currently accessing your MySQL server (stop services like apache2, postfix or whatever normally accesses the MySQL server). If you made yourself sure, that you are alone in the dark, apply the patch and force a mysql upgrade with the following commands:

```
# zcat mysql-patch-5.5.55.sql.gz | mysql -uroot -p mysql
# mysql_upgrade --force -uroot -p
```

If anything worked without any error, restart your MySQL service:

```
# service mysql stop
# service mysql start
```

After that, try to create a testuser to see, if the patch has been applied correctly:

```
# mysql -uroot -p
```

> CREATE USER 'Testuser123'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'Pass0worZ';

You should get a message like:

> Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Now, you can safely delete your testuser again, with:

> DROP USER 'Testuser123'@'localhost';

Anyway, if something went wrong, restore your backup and try again ;)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Why instead of just post a link to a patch you wrote dont' you first EXPLAIN what the patch does and what are the differences between MySQL versions you found? Does your patch send other people's MySQL credentials to someone else??

Answer (score 2):

In my case, with Debian 8 and MySQL 5.5, `mysql_upgrade --force -uroot -p` wont fix the issue.

I needed upgrading to MySQL 5.6 first and then run the command above.

http://www.debiantutorials.com/install-mysql-server-5-6-debian-7-8/

Answer (score 2):

When migrating from mysql 5.5 to 5.7, (by using a full mysqldump and then the source command) I had the error only when I tried to edit or add a user

> ERROR 1805 (HY000): Column count of mysql.user is wrong. Expected 45,
>   found 42. The table is probably corrupted

Similar to some others here I did

> sudo mysql_upgrade -u root -p  #sudo so it can write a log sudo
>
> service mysql restart

And that fixed the issue, I could add and edit users again. I would have added this small difference as a comment to one of the similar answers, but I don't have the reputation yet

Comment: This doesn't work for me. **mysql_upgrade -u root -p** gives me error: `mysql_upgrade: Got error: 1862: Your password has expired. To log in you must change it using a client that supports expired passwords. while connecting to the MySQL server`

Comment: you can reset the password on the command line directly, such as in this example: https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/mysql-resetting-a-lost-mysql-root-password/

Comment: I solved that password issue but still giving me `ERROR 1805 (HY000): Column count of MySQL.user is wrong. Expected 45, found 42. The table is probably corrupted` when I try to modify user privileges or delete users.

Answer (score 1):

I've ran into the same issue today.. 
The solution for me was to manually add the missing columns to the user table.

**Beware - Use at your own risk**

The newly added columns with mysql.5.5.55 are:

```
plugin, authentication_string, Create_tablespace_priv
```

They need to be added in a specific oder:

```
use mysql;
alter Table user ADD Create_tablespace_priv enum('N','Y')  DEFAULT 'N' NOT NULL AFTER Trigger_priv;
alter Table user ADD plugin char(64) DEFAULT '';
alter Table user ADD authentication_string text DEFAULT NULL;
```

After this, I was able to again, modify the user table.

Answer (score 1):

After and upgrade I had "Column count of mysql.user is wrong. Expected 45, found 46. The table is probably corrupted" I was having trouble logging in so i fired up the db:

```
mysqld --console --skip-grant-tables
```

logged in and there was an extra column compared to my default table "Is_role" so i removed it:

```
ALTER TABLE `user` DROP COLUMN `is_role`;
```

restarted mysqld and we are all good.

Comment: This saved me. Thanks!  I compared a similar server's tables and this was the one extra column when updating 5.7.

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved my problem this way:

1) Start mysql: `mysqld –-console –-skip-grant-tables –-skip-external-locking` (keep the terminal open)

2) Execute: `mysqlcheck –-repair mysql user`

Source: https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,652134,652135#msg-652135

Comment: This doesn't work. It's giving me

`mysqlcheck: Got error: 1862: Your password has expired. To log in you must change it using a client that supports expired passwords. when trying to connect`

Comment: @SmitPatel your problem is unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

Quiet the same error message : Column count of mysql.user is wrong. Expected 42, found 43. The table is probably corrupted.
This is not the solution but a circumvention ... I backuped all my databases from mysql 5.5.55-0+deb8u1 and restored them to mysql 5.7.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 until this bug is not resolved.
Hard job to update all connections but usefull.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to add a new user or even change the permission of any existing users and getting the error, firstly I would suggest to grant full permission to the root users, and then adding new users.

```
sudo mysql
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'ccuser'@'localhost';
```

And then,

```
CREATE USER 'new_user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'new_password';
```

Answer (score 0):

**In case you do not want to Upgrade the MySQL using `mysql_upgrade --force -uroot -p` or `mysql -u root -p` as it may interfere with the database,
as if the database may be important i.e. it may either be running on a live server, or too big to take a backup and restore it, and you may not want to take that risk of getting it deleted from a live server, then you may simply rectify the error after understanding it line by line.**

**It may be different in your case but, In my case**

**I had to give privileges to a remote host as: `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON some_db_name_abc.* to 'root'@'xxx.xxx.x.xxx' IDENTIFIED BY 'test123';`**

***and the error was*** `#1558 - Column count of mysql.user is wrong. Expected 42, found 39. Created with MySQL 50173, now running 50562. Please use mysql_upgrade to fix this error.`

[image]

So Basically 3 columns named `Create_tablespace_priv`, `plugin` and `authentication_string`   were absent from the table named `user` of database `mysql`. The `column names`, their `position` in the table and their `datatypes`, I came to know from another testing server, which I added as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE mysql.user
  ADD Create_tablespace_priv ENUM('N','Y') NOT NULL
    AFTER Trigger_priv;
    
ALTER TABLE mysql.user
  ADD plugin CHAR(64) NOT NULL
    AFTER max_user_connections; 
    
    
ALTER TABLE mysql.user
  ADD authentication_string TEXT NOT NULL
    AFTER plugin;
```

And the query to give privileges to a remote host ran successfully after it

In case you made mistake, then you can delete the added column from the table as:

```
ALTER TABLE mysql.user DROP COLUMN plugin;
```

Answer (score 0):

start your MySQL/MariaDB database server on local host then
if you have a root password?

```
sudo mysql_upgrade --force -uroot -p
```

else (if root password is null or No)

```
sudo mysql_upgrade --force -uroot
```